# Unable to get AngularJS controller object

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-controller

In my non-angular code I am getting controller object through following code

```
var controllerElement = angular.element('[ng-controller="' + controllerName + '"]');
var controller = controllerElement.controller();
```

It was working perfectly until day before yesterday when instead of controller object controller object has some $get.h {}

Following code returns correct controller object but there is a scenario in which angular is throwing exception:

```
var $controller = injector.get("$controller");
var controller = $controller(controllerName, { $scope: scope });
```

Could you please help me find figure out what is the problem with former approach i.e. controllerElement.controller();

EDIT:
Found another issue with latter approach that it instantiates a new controller object instead of returning the original one associated with the element.

Comment: what is the value returned by `controllerElement.length`

Comment: contrllerElement has length 1 i.e. correct element is found

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend not to mix angular code with external JS. Every time you are calling a `Controller`, it will created indeed a new object, but as far as I understood from your question, you probably want to do some manipulation in it or its data. For persistent data across controllers or states of your application you should use a `Service` or a `Factory`, and manipulating it should happen in it, or from a `Controller` not some random JS somewhere.